# Why do I have do assign subquery to a variable outside of my main query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

In the GetTransfers() method below I have to assign the result of GetAllocations() to a variable outside of my main query otherwise the query fails.  Why do I have to do that?  Is there a better way?
When the query fails I get this error:

{System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[XCBusinessLogic.Presentation.Allocation] GetAllocations()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

This query works:

```
public IQueryable<Transfer> GetTransfers()
    {
        IQueryable<Allocation> wxyz = GetAllocations();

        IQueryable<Transfer> query =
            from transfer in Context.XC_TRANSFERS
            //let wxyz = GetAllocations()
            join trader in Context.MGRS on transfer.TRADER_ID equals trader.MGR_NO
            join ssm in Context.SSM_CORES on transfer.SSM_ID equals ssm.SSM_ID
            join desk in Context.XC_DESKS on transfer.DESK_ID equals desk.DESK_ID

            select new Transfer
            {
                // snip
                _AllocationList = wxyz.Where(x => x.TRANSFER_ID == transfer.TRANSFER_ID)
            };
        return query;

    }
```

This query fails:

```
public IQueryable<Transfer> GetTransfers()
    {
        //IQueryable<Allocation> wxyz = GetAllocations();

        IQueryable<Transfer> query =
            from transfer in Context.XC_TRANSFERS
            let wxyz = GetAllocations()
            join trader in Context.MGRS on transfer.TRADER_ID equals trader.MGR_NO
            join ssm in Context.SSM_CORES on transfer.SSM_ID equals ssm.SSM_ID
            join desk in Context.XC_DESKS on transfer.DESK_ID equals desk.DESK_ID

            select new Transfer
            {
                // snip
                _AllocationList = wxyz.Where(x => x.TRANSFER_ID == transfer.TRANSFER_ID)
            };
        return query;

    }
```

This query fails:

```
public IQueryable<Transfer> GetTransfers()
    {
        //IQueryable<Allocation> wxyz = GetAllocations();

        IQueryable<Transfer> query =
            from transfer in Context.XC_TRANSFERS
            //let wxyz = GetAllocations()
            join trader in Context.MGRS on transfer.TRADER_ID equals trader.MGR_NO
            join ssm in Context.SSM_CORES on transfer.SSM_ID equals ssm.SSM_ID
            join desk in Context.XC_DESKS on transfer.DESK_ID equals desk.DESK_ID

            select new Transfer
            {
                // snip
                _AllocationList = GetAllocations().Where(x => x.TRANSFER_ID == transfer.TRANSFER_ID)
            };
        return query;

    }
```

GetAllocations Method:

```
public IQueryable<Allocation> GetAllocations()
    {
        IQueryable<Allocation> query =
            from alloc in Context.XC_ALLOCATIONS
            join acm in Context.ACMS on alloc.ACCT_NO equals acm.ACCT_NO
            join b in Context.BUM_DETAILS.Where(x => x.FIRM_NO == 1 && x.CATEGORY_ID == 1937) on acm.ACCT_NO equals b.ACCT_NO into bumDetails
            from bumDetail in bumDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where acm.FIRM_NO == 1
            select new Allocation
            {
                AccountName = acm.ACCT_NAME
                // snip

            };
        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the problem by using `join` with your method followed by an `into`

```
IQueryable<Transfer> query =
            from transfer in Context.XC_TRANSFERS
            join allocation in GetAllocations() on transfer.TRANSFER_ID equals allocation.TRANSFER_ID into allocationList
            join trader in Context.MGRS on transfer.TRADER_ID equals trader.MGR_NO
            join ssm in Context.SSM_CORES on transfer.SSM_ID equals ssm.SSM_ID
            join desk in Context.XC_DESKS on transfer.DESK_ID equals desk.DESK_ID

            select new Transfer
            {
                // snip
                _AllocationList = allocationList
            };
```

Comment: I love you right now!  See below for the issue I had and how this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Linq to Entities translate everything in the query `from transfer in Context.XC_TRANSFERS ...` into SQL. So the only expressions that are allowed inside that query are ones that can easily be translated to SQL.

Linq to Entities cannot figure out how a .NET method like `GetAllocations()` works. How should it do that? There could be any form of crazy code inside a method. How could it turn that into SQL?

In your case the method actually contains another Linq to Entities query. Maybe you could copy-paste one query into the interior of the other. But I don't think that would improve your code!

So just keep the working solution you have.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue and the answer from Aducci did it for me.  This was what I was trying to do:

```
query = from x in query
        where GetServicesQuery(db, options).Any(service => /*my criteria*/)
        select x;
```

It was resolved by doing this as Aducci suggested:

```
query = from x in query
        join service in GetServicesQuery(db, localOptions) on x.ID equals service.ID into services
        where services.Any(service => /*my criteria*/)
        select x;
```

I am posting this solution because my case was different from above (needing the subquery in the where not the select).  If anyone ever stumbles onto this thread with the same issue as me, hopefully this will save them some searching around.

This one was stressing me out since GetServicesQuery has a lot of criteria that I don't want to keep repeating.